# Calling base and derived static methods of a type variable

Tags: java, generics, static

I have the following example:

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        A<ConcreteErrorHandler> a = new A<ConcreteErrorHandler>();
        a.m(); //Exception here!
    }

    public static class AbstractErrorHandler {
        public static void handle(){ 
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented");
        }
    }

    public static class ConcreteErrorHandler extends AbstractErrorHandler{
        public static void handle(){ 
            System.out.println("Concrete handler");
        }
    }

    public static class A<T extends AbstractErrorHandler>{
        public void m(){
            T.handle();
        }
    }
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/Jnkn9U)

Why the method of the base class is called, but not of the derived? The signatures of the `handle()` methods are perfectly the same. I know that static methods don't inherit, but shouldn't a compile-time error be thrown in my case then?

Could someone explain that behavior?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for this is that the compiler **doesn't know** which exact subtype of `AbstractErrorHandler` will be replacing `T` at Runtime. That's why it just binds the method call `T.handle()` to the `AbstractErrorHandler.handle()` method.

The problem here is that you're mixing inheritance with the `static` features of the classes in Java.

In order to have this working (correctly), you have to get rid of the `static` modifier for the `.handle()` methods and keep an instance of `T` in the `A` class. This `T` instance (at Runtime) will be some specific subclass of `AbstractErrorHandler` and then the **actual** `.handle()` method will be executed.

For example:

```
class Ideone {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        A<ConcreteErrorHandler> a = new A<ConcreteErrorHandler>(new ConcreteErrorHandler());
        a.m();
    }

    public static class AbstractErrorHandler {
        public void handle() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented");
        }
    }

    public static class ConcreteErrorHandler extends AbstractErrorHandler {
        public void handle() {
            System.out.println("Concrete handler");
        }
    }

    public static class A<T extends AbstractErrorHandler> {

        T instance;

        A(T instance) {
            this.instance = instance;
        }

        public void m() {
            instance.handle();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I provided the exact type at compile time. `A<ConcreteErrorHandler> a = new A<ConcreteErrorHandler>();` The type known at compile time.

Comment: You provided the type out of scope of the `m` method.

Comment: @St.Antario Java generics aren't templates like in C++. The class declaration doesn't know about the parameterization you give it somewhere else.

Comment: @Radiodef Actually, it was come from Alexandrescu's policies. But what's wrong with my code? I'd like to understand that behavior.

Comment: The Java compiler does something named type erasure where the type of the generics is removed from the code. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genMethods.html

Answer (score 6):

[*4.4. Type Variables*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4) tells us that:

> The members of a type variable `X` with bound `T & I1 & ... & In` are the members of the intersection type `T & I1 & ... & In` **appearing at the point where the type variable is declared**.

Therefore the members of `T extends AbstractErrorHandler` are the members of `AbstractErrorHandler`. `T.handle();` refers to `AbstractErrorHandler.handle();`.

Answer (score 4):

The erasure of a bounded type parameter is the bound (and in the case of a bound intersection, the first type in the bound). So in your case, `T extends AbstractErrorHandler` is erased to `AbstractErrorHandler` and your method is effectively replaced by:

```
 public void m() { AbstractErrorHandler.handle(); }
```

See for example [JLS 4.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6)

> The erasure of a type variable (§4.4) is the erasure of its leftmost bound.

Answer (score 3):

Because basically your method `m` will be *compiled* into

```
public void m(){
    AbstractErrorHandler.handle();
}
```

Comment: Why that, I provided the type at compile time?

Comment: No you didn't.  You provided `T`.   While it may be possible to have the compiler do what you think it should, clearly it doesn't.

Comment: While true, your answer is already apparent from the question. The OP is instead asking *why* this happens.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is because `static` is class scoped and you are telling the compiler to use AbstractErrorHandler implicitly by using `T extends AbstractErrorHandler`.

The runtime will assume the highest class level since type erasure occurs at runtime.

The implementation of `m` only uses `T` which is an AbstractErrorHandler, despite the fact you declared it to be the concrete type in the main method, which is not in the scope of the `m` method.

Comment: Don't see how it explains anything. Honestly, I was expected to look at JLS reference or some.

Answer (score 2):

Java compiler erases all type parameters in generic code, you cannot verify which parameterized type for a generic type is being used at runtime. Therefore upper bound type `AbstractErrorHandler` is used.

see for more details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because **you are using generics and java static methods** that are hidden not overriden. At compile time the only know information is the `AbstractErrorHandler` class (generics works at a compile time in java, there is no bytecode with generics information) and the method called is the one of the class. 
If you change the method handle form static to "instance" the implementation called is the "right" one (because the method is overridden not hidden )as in the example below .

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        A<AbstractErrorHandler> a = new A<AbstractErrorHandler>();
        a.m(new ConcreteErrorHandler()); //Exception here!
    }

    public  static class AbstractErrorHandler {
        public  void handle(){ 
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented");
        }
    }

    public static class ConcreteErrorHandler extends AbstractErrorHandler{
        public  void handle(){ 
            System.out.println("Concrete handler");
        }
    }

    public static class A<T extends AbstractErrorHandler>{
        public void m(T t){
            t.handle();
        }
    }
}
```